# I need to make an add button to create an <a> element from input of text box

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hello I have looked all over the internet and stack overflow and I can't find any code to make a button connected to a text field to add an  element. with the text inside of it with a checkbox next to it so please help me :).

(edit: it hit me before answers came;)

```css
a{
  background-color: #4CAF50; /*Original code; w3 schools*/
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

and change the document.createelement('p') to document.createelement('a')

Comment: [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`addEventListener()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) or [`onclick`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-button-onclick-javascript-click-event-tutorial/) should help you get an idea on how you could make an attempt at doing this.

Comment: I think "looked all over the internet" might be an exaggeration  for this one ;)

Comment: Please explain the question better. That might help with the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create an element, you need to use `document.createElement()`. We use an event listener to see when the user clicks the button and then grab the value, create the element, set the anchor tag href, set the value as the text for the anchor tag and then append it to the container.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('addButton');
let container = document.getElementById('container');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Get the value of the input
  let inputData = document.getElementById('input_field').value;
  
  // Create an anchor element and add text to tag
  let newElement = document.createElement('a');
  newElement.innerHTML = inputData;
  
  // Set anchor attribute
  newElement.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.com');
  
  // Attached the new element to the container
  container.appendChild(newElement);
  
  // Insert break tags after each anchor element inserted
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br />');
  
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input_field">
<button id="addButton">Add anchor tag</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```